# How to merge PayPal SDK and Braintree SDK in android studio

Tags: android, paypal, braintree

I want to implement the PayPal payment and Braintree Payment gateway.

I have use PayPalAndroidSDK-2.9.10.jar inside the libs and

compile 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:1.6.5' inside the app.gradle file.

The problem is there is a duplicate class in PayPal and Braintree SDK.

I Need to merge both SDK .

Note : PayPal and Braintree work when run in sepately.

Comment: which is the duplicate class?

Comment: PayPal Package is inside the both PayPal and Braintree SDK that whole package classes is duplicate.

Comment: If both are the same version, I guess you can remove the paypal jar altogether?

Comment: In PayPal Jar contain Payment package but there is no Payment package in Braintree. Also Paypal is not working.

Comment: @SivaSonai You can integrate with both PayPal and Braintree by using only the Braintree SDK. There is a [guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/overview/android/v1) on how to accomplish this in the Braintree documentation.

Comment: @Ryan, Thnk for response while using Braintree as Paypal it doesn't generate any client token, At the same time I need to pay with using client token as Braintree method and also need to pay with Paypal SDK